Injecting a Scoped Service into DbContextFactory with Singleton service lifetime when you are using Blazor Server
Thanks to the stackoverflow community I learned that since I'm using ef core with Blazor Server, I must use DbContextFactory because AddDbContext can be problematic, so I add my service as follows
builder.Services.AddDbContextFactory<AppDbContext>(options =>
{
    options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("Connection"));
});

This adds the service as a singleton.
In the class where I define my DBContext I override the SaveChangesAsync method to add the creation date and the user who created the record. In the case of the user I send it with a scoped service that I use in my app to share the User State, the service is filled with information when the app starts.
builder.Services.AddScoped<UserState>();

and following the information from some blogs and videos on how to inject a scoped service into a singleton service, I do it using IServiceScopeFactory
private readonly IServiceScopeFactory _serviceScopeFactory;

public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> options, IServiceScopeFactory serviceScopeFactory) : base(options)
{
     _serviceScopeFactory = serviceScopeFactory;
}

public override Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = new CancellationToken())
{
    using IServiceScope scope = _serviceScopeFactory.CreateAsyncScope();
    var _userState = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<UserState>();

    foreach (var entry in ChangeTracker.Entries<EntityBase>())
    {
      switch (entry.State)
      {
            case EntityState.Added:
                entry.Entity.CreatedAt = DateTime.Now;
                   if (_userState.UserName is not null)
                        entry.Entity.CreatedBy = _userState.UserName;
                   break;
             case EntityState.Modified:
                   entry.Entity.EditedAt = DateTime.Now;
                   if (_userState.UserName is not null)
                        entry.Entity.EditedBy = _userState.UserName;
                   break;
       }
     }

    return base.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
}

This certainly injects the service but it creates a new instance with empty data, I understand that this happens because I am creating a scope that is different from the scope of the UserState service I am injecting.
So I would like to know how I can pass the name of the user who creates or modifies the record to my DBConextFactory.
Thank you very much.

Update
This article https://blog.jeremylikness.com/blog/multitenancy-with-ef-core-in-blazor-server-apps/ helped me understand that depending on the scenario, in Blazor Server you can use the DBContextFactory with a Scoped ServiceLifetime, as long as you create and destroy the dbcontext every time you use it, and having this ServiceLifetime I could inject the Scoped service where I have the user data.

This question is similar to: Scoped service in DBContext with DBContextFactory can't resolve from root provider. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Thanks steve for your reply, the difference is that in the question you mention the solution they give is to add the dbcontextfactory as scoped, which does work for asp.net core, but the documentation explains you should not do it with blazor server. I edited the title of the question just mentioning that this is about Blazor Server, hopefully that clarifies the problem a little more.

Perhaps consider using ProtectedSessionStore for your UserState details rather than trying to work around the fact that a singleton cannot access a scoped lifetime instance as a dependency. I have done work-arounds in MVC by registering IHttpContextAccessor (Singleton) where factories etc. can access info from the current scope data managed by things like .Session. Not directly applicable to Blazor but you should be able to use the ProtectedSessionStore to manage per-session data.

Thank very much Steve I'm gonna checkout ProtectedSessionStore to try your suggestion.
